# Connectivity vs. density for random, small world and scale-free networks

Tags: graph-theory, networks, igraph

I am trying to understand a paper by reconstructing the the analyses discussed in the **Validation study** section, however, I am confused when it comes to how a network metric is used. Specifically, the authors discuss that they manipulated the **connectivity metric** in order to generate sparse networks.

I know that in graph theory connectivity refers to:

> [[...] the minimum number of elements (nodes or edges) that need to be removed to disconnect the remaining nodes from each other.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory))

**Question 1:** What exactly does **connectivity** refer to in the paragraph below? Is it *network density* or *degree centrality*?

**Question 2:** Also, I don't understand how increasing the *preferential attachment* parameter (i.e., $P_{attach}$) affects the network sparsity in the case of scale-free networks. The authors mention that *only one edge is added per node at each iteration*, so, regardless of the preferential attachment, the resulting number of edges in the graph should remain the same, right?

This is the representative paragraph from the paper in question:

> The level of connectivity of the networks was chosen to generate
>   sparse networks. For this reason, in case of random networks, the
>   probability of a connection ($P_{conn}$) between two nodes was set to
>   0.1, 0.2, and 0.3. For small world networks, the neighbourhood was set to 2, and for scale-free networks only one edge is added per node at
>   each iteration in the graph generating process. To obtain awide
>   variety of well known graph structures, the rewiring probability
>   ($P_{rewire}$) in small world networks was set to 0.1, 0.5 and 1, and
>   the power of preferential attachment ($P_{attach}$) in scale-free
>   networks was set to 1, 2 and 3. For the condition with 100 nodes, we
>   used different levels of connectivity for random and scale-free
>   networks (random networks: $P_{conn}=$ .05, .1, and .15; scale-free
>   networks: $P_{attach}=$ 1, 1.25, and 1.5). Otherwise, nodes will have
>   too many connections.
>
> — [Van Borkulo et al. (2014; p. 4)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep05918)

Comment: $P_{attach} = 1, 1.25, 1.5$. What, the scale-free attachers are so good that they have up to 150% chance of successfully attaching?  Anyhow, what is the meaning of $P_{attach}$ If this is not a mistake, can you tell us what $P_{attach}$ means?

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone for your input! I am quite sure that $P_{attach}$, as dsecribed in that paragraph, refers to the power of the preferential attachment, presumably, as discussed [here (i.e., page 511, paragraph 2)](http://www.biocomp.unibo.it/gigi/CB/articoli/barabasiScience.pdf). I am confused because I don't understand how can $P_{attach}$ affect the network sparsity.

Comment: Whoops, i missed that. Anyhow, maybe (or not) http://www2.unb.ca/~ddu/6634/Lecture_notes/Lecture7_network_models.pdf will provide you some background to help understand this paper.